# CDN and Local bootstrap CSS Render Differently

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have an app that loads just fine when using the CDN for bootstrap files. If I download the files from the URL in the link and load them locally, they all appear to work the same EXCEPT for bootstrap.css. Bootstrap styling definitely loads, but a select box goes full screen width (which I don't want), which it doesn't do when loading from the CDN. I need all files local. Why is a local copy of the CDN's CSS behaving differently? How can I fix this?

Clarification, if I use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
```

it doesn't render correctly, but if I use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

it does render correctly. HTML snippet in question below:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Styling -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Project.css" type="text/css" />
...
    <div id="container" class="container">
                <div id = "controls-holder" class="row">
                    <div id="team-selector" class="col-sm-3">
                        <select id="team-select" class="form-control">
                            <option>Choose...</option>   
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="team-tab-selector" class="col-sm-5">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                          <li class="active nav-item nav-link" id="nav-item-x">y</li>
                          <li class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-item-y">y</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="controls-links" class="col-sm-4">
                        <span class=>Links
                            <button type="button" id="link-one-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-2">Primary</button>
                            <button type="button" id="link-two-btn" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Secondary</button>
                        </span>

                    </div>    
                </div>
...
</div>
```

Comment: It's not possible, please see your CDN and local files version is matching or not

Comment: That's why I'm baffled. I put https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css in my browser, save the file, point my html at it with a link tag as in my question, and it renders differently.

Comment: weird but not possible, I think its case of specificity, some properties are overriding by your CSS, please check

Comment: The only way it would be overriding is through a race condition. I'm going to add the html snippet in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodejs to get the bootstrap CSS and JS to your project.

```js
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Move the javascript files into our /src/js folder
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('sass', function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./src"  
    });

    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
}));

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('js','serve'));
```

Comment: I'm trying to use pre-compiled bootstrap here. My boostrap.css and boostrap.js live in the static HTML.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JYhTJ_w6542DMe_i6wp2UCXyzkc2NAMz?usp=sharing 
You could try with my files.

Comment: I still have the issue using your file. I'm wondering if there's some weird race condition going on. Loading from the CDN I see it use @media, and when I load it locally I don't. It's giving a container a different max-width. I've managed to force everything to where it needs to be. It's like it's ignoring the x in "col-sm-x". I still don't know why it's doing this.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had this same problem. Here's what I did.

I'm learning Flask and am following a Corey Shafer's tutorial. I had this same problem, so here's what worked for me. I created a `static` folder within the same directory as my python script. I placed the `bootstrap.css` file in there and called it with this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.css') }}">
```

One thing to remember, make sure you import `url_for` from Flask in your python script if you're using Flask:

`from flask import url_for`

Hope this helps your my friend.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me and the solution was to use locally bootstrap.css instead of bootstrap.min.css. I don't know why but it worked.